# Can we access the LocationManager class to use it with MonoDroid?

Tags: xamarin.android, locationmanager

Do I have access to the LocationManager class in MonoDroid?
Is it possible to use all the functionalities of LocationManager in MonoDroid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! See here:

[Android.Locations.LocationManager Members](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Locations.LocationManager%2f%2a)